# Unable to open file XML.XMLINTF.OBJ

Tags: c++, xml, c++builder, teechart, c++builder-xe7

I developed all my code at C++ Builder XE with TeeChart 2011. So, now I want to migrate to C++ Builder XE7 with TeeChart 2015.

When I try to compile my code, the message error is presented:

> [ilink32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'XML.XMLINTF.OBJ'

I don't use any XML and I don´t have any XML link in my code.

So, I don't know why this error occurs.

What can I do to correct this error?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a new simple application? If so, can you share it so we can investigate it?

Comment: I solved including the pragma link. However, I will try to do a new simple application with the same error to investigate a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure you are not using/linking any of XML units in your code, then probably something along the 3rd party components you are using are linking it.

The solution is simple: you just need to add the XML runtime packages to your project. I like to add them directly using `#pragma link` in one of my units, for example:

```
#pragma link "xmlrtl.bpi"
```

You could also add this directly to the project, with the "Add..." context menu. Adding this on the runtime packages list option in the Project Options should work, but in my experience, it rarely does.

A final option could be to remove and add again the unit where the Xmlintf unit is being linked, so the IDE can identify the missing package and add it, but if you don't have any unit that `#pragma link`s it then it's of no use.

Comment: Thank you for help. I included the link in main file and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using `#pragma link "xmlrtl.bpi"` could cause access violation. Instead, I change to `link xmlrtl.lib` and everything is fine!